# How to do components wise routing in NEXT.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-link

I have a **sidebar** which contains some tabs like **profile**, **settings**, **insights** now when click on one of the **tab** it should show particular content where **routes** should change but page should not be **refresh**.

I have no idea how to do?

Comment: This question should include more details and codes and clarify the problem.

Comment: You should provide more details. But as I get your question, you should use Link from next/link and use it like <Link href="route">some route name</Link>. Don't use just a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nextjs you can use its routing mechanism to route between pages.

Next 13 use server rendered components, and supports other approaches too, which means it is not strictly client side SPA like routing.

See https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/linking-and-navigating

If you want to prevent routing with reloading the ui, you can use shallow routing.
See https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing